# Cannot recognize input near '|' 'sed' ''s/[[:space:]]\+/,/g'' in table source

Tags: java, csv, hive, export

I am trying to execute hive command to export table data to csv file using the below command from Java program, but I am getting "cannot recognize input near '|'".
HIVE command :

```
hive -e "SELECT * from table1" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > /table.csv
```

> Error:NoViableAltException(5@[180:25: (props= tableProperties )?])
>   FAILED: ParseException line 1:32 cannot recognize input near '|' 'sed' ''s/[[:space:]]+/,/g'' in table source

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: have you tried using your database in hive execute also ??

Comment: Yes. I have tried "select * from dbname.table1" also.